# Converting a D object pointer to void* and passing to a callback

Tags: pointers, garbage-collection, d, void-pointers

I want to convert a D class pointer into `void*`, pass this `void*` pointer together with the pointer to my callback `extern(C)` function to a C library routine.

The C library routine will call my callback `extern(C)` function, which will convert `void*` back to the class pointer and use the object of this class.

The trouble: I heard that GC objects may be moved to other locations (maybe not in current D version but in a future). Does this mean that my `void*` pointer may become invalid (no more point to my object)?

If the problem really exists, how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the GC to hold on to the pointer as a root and furthermore, tell it not to move it on you with the `import core.memory; GC.addRoot(ptr);` function. This example shows it in full:

http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/core.memory.GC.addRoot.html#examples

```
// Typical C-style callback mechanism; the passed function
// is invoked with the user-supplied context pointer at a
// later point.
extern(C) void addCallback(void function(void*), void*);

// Allocate an object on the GC heap (this would usually be
// some application-specific context data).
auto context = new Object;

// Make sure that it is not collected even if it is no
// longer referenced from D code (stack, GC heap, …).
GC.addRoot(cast(void*)context);

// Also ensure that a moving collector does not relocate
// the object.
GC.setAttr(cast(void*)context, GC.BlkAttr.NO_MOVE);

// Now context can be safely passed to the C library.
addCallback(&myHandler, cast(void*)context);

extern(C) void myHandler(void* ctx)
{
   // Assuming that the callback is invoked only once, the
   // added root can be removed again now to allow the GC
   // to collect it later.
   GC.removeRoot(ctx);
   GC.clrAttr(ctx, GC.BlkAttr.NO_MOVE);

   auto context = cast(Object)ctx;
   // Use context here…
}
```

Comment: I'd exchange `GC.removeRoot(ctx);` and `GC.clrAttr(ctx, GC.BlkAttr.NO_MOVE);`, because in OOP resource should be freed in reverse order of their acquision.

Comment: Will your code work if instead: `scope auto context = new Object;` (that is Object allocated on the stack rather than on the heap)?

Comment: Not in general - the danger of the callback is that it will outlive the scope of the caller, which means the stack allocated object is definitely dead. If the callback only happens in scope, it doesn't matter either way - the stack reference to the GC'd object will also be live anyway. (And if it just runs inside the C function, the D GC will never run anyway, unless there is another thread triggering it.)

Comment: I wanted to ask whether `GC.addRoot(cast(void*)context);` will work if `context` is pointing onto the stack. I suspect it may segfault, throw an exception, or lead to undefined behavior. Is my fear founded?

Comment: It is undefined; the documentation only says what it does if it points to a GC block or null.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Adam D. Ruppe's answer but reorganized.

Even better OO code:

```
import core.memory : GC;

class UnmovableObject {
    this() {
        //GC.addRoot(cast(void*)this); // prevents finalization
        GC.setAttr(cast(void*)this, GC.BlkAttr.NO_MOVE);
    }
    ~this() {
       //GC.removeRoot(cast(void*)this);
       GC.clrAttr(cast(void*)this, GC.BlkAttr.NO_MOVE);
   }
}
```

Comment: That destructor will never run unless called manually (with the `.destroy(obj)` function) since while the object is a GC root, it will never be collected and thus never destroyed.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe That it cannot be done with a destructor is really bad. RAI idiom is broken here. I suggest to devise a new D language feature to solve this problem

Comment: Hm, well: Why to `addRoot` and `removeRoot`? `setAttr`/`clrAttr` seems to work for any GC pointer, not only for a root. So I propose to remove `C.addRoot(cast(void*)this);` and `GC.removeRoot(cast(void*)this);`. I think after this my OO code will work. Right?

Comment: Destructors are only triggered when the object is destroyed. A GC root is *never* destroyed (unless you manually do it). That's the whole point of that function! The original problem was the GC might free the block while C was holding on to it, because D's GC can't see C's internal memory. By adding it as a root, it tell's D's GC not to try to automatically free it until you tell it it is OK (via the removeRoot) function. This protects it from being freed while C is still holding on to it.